# NestJS : How to bubble up/propagate exception?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

In NestJS, we can had Exceptions to route or to specific module using `@UseFilters()` or to the whole application using `useGlobalFilters()`.

So, how can I bubble up/propagate the route or module level caught exception to the global exception filter ?

For example, `AuthExceptionFilter` is attached to the Users' controller and there's a global exception filter called `HttpExceptionFilter`.

In specific scenario, for instance, when auth exception's message is "X", I want this specific error to be bubbled up / propagated to the global exception filter (`HttpExceptionFilter`), so that it knows how to handle it.

Or in another case, I just want to add few properties to the exception from `AuthExceptionFilter` before letting it handled by `HttpExceptionFilter`.

so, basically I want to bubble up or propagate or rethrow error caught in specific exception filter to global(generic) exception filter.

Answer (score 1):

I used to think this wasn't possible, but I tested again and found a solution.

### For Express Based Nest Applications

For express apps, we can use `host.switchToHttp().getNext()` to get the `next` middleware and call `next(exception)` to pass from the router/controller level filter to the global filter.

### For Fastify Based Nest Applications

For fastify apps, we don't have the same `next` middleware to work with, but we can `throw exception` instead and move from the router/controller filter to the global filter.

---

Here's the code I was using to test both:

#### controller.filter.ts

```js
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class ControllerFilter<T> implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: T, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    console.log('In the Controller Filter');
    const next = host.switchToHttp().getNext();
    console.log(next);
    if (next) {
      next(exception);
    } else {
      throw exception;
    }
  }
}
```

#### global.filter.ts

```js
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class GlobalFilter<T> implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: T, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    console.log('In the global filter');
    console.log(exception);
    host
      .switchToHttp()
      .getResponse()
      .send({ ...exception, from: GlobalFilter.name });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way I think, but it didn't work.